# Add submenu to account icon

Tags: html, css

How can I make a user account to show me register and login in line as sub-menu of it?
 Please help me cuz I don't know how to make submenu of account icon to register and login accounts.
Please I need help.

```css
/* Style the subnav content - positioned absolute */
.subnav-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5;
  background-color: black;
  width: 5%;
  z-index: 1;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/js/all.js" data-auto-a11y="true"></script>
<div class="subnav">
    <a href="#register"><i class="fas fa-user" style="font-size: 16px; color: white;"></i></a>
    <div class="subnav-content">
        <a href="#link1"><i class="fas fa-cash-register"></i></a>
        <a href="#link2"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Victor, could you please explain how do you want your sub menu content to be triggered ? I mean when you hover over the parent menu item or when you click it ?

Comment: When I click on parent menu item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add flex display. I removed width property to avoid overflow ( You can specify width of course )

```css
/* Style the subnav content - positioned absolute */
.subnav-content {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  background-color: black;      
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/js/all.js" data-auto-a11y="true"></script>
<div class="subnav">
    <a href="#register"><i class="fas fa-user" style="font-size: 16px; color: white;"></i></a>
    <div class="subnav-content">
        <a href="#link1"><i class="fas fa-cash-register"></i></a>
        <a href="#link2"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```